# Text widget font not appearing correctly

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, flutter-layout, statefulwidget

I've created a separate page with a `StatefulWidget` inside my Flutter app, and it has a `Text` widget inside of it.

However, when testing my app, the text does not render as intended - instead it shows up in a weird font with yellow underlining.

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ListsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _ListsPageState();
  }
}

class _ListsPageState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Text('Log in page'),
    );
  }
}
```

[Results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EbgS.png)

Comment: you might need to add a textsyle property to the text widget. This would help you style the text as you want see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove Material Widget just return Text Widget Only, and please try to use the Stateless widget for better performance. Here's the example code

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:show_case/diementions/text_size.dart';

class TextWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      'Login Page',
      style: kLabelStyle,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the app styling found in a widget higher in the tree. The text widget searches up the tree for the app default text style or one in another widget. If you wrap the Text widget in a Scaffold, that will include different styling.
See the her comment in the following code for where to try setting the default style:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData( //HERE
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also try wrapping the Text widget like this:

```dart
DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),
  child: Text('Log in page'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set style in textwidget

```
Text("", style: TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.none),)
```